# How to format Elasticsearch highlight data that contains html?

Tags: c#, html, regex, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 1.7 highlighting on a c# webapp but the data that's being highlighted has html in it. Currently I am stripping out the html with this regex

```
Regex.Replace(rawHighlight, "<.*?>", string.Empty)
```

The problem comes in when the highlight does not finish a complete html tag. For example, if my pre and post tags are `@highlight--` and `--highlight@` I might get back a result like this:

`<div>This is an @highlight--example--highlight@ </d`

So the regex will remove the first `div` but not the one that is not complete ie. `</d`

So this is sort of two questions in one. Is there a regex to remove the malformed html after the first regex is run (that will be on the end or start of the string) or is there some better way of using Elasticsearch's `highlight` so that I won't have to parse the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you did already asked yourself that, but for completion:
why would you have html in your search index? and if you really have to, then add a second (scripted) field, that contains a parsed html (without tags), and use it for highlighting.